# Mockito Junit jupiter api not resolving the parameter JsonObject

Tags: json, mockito, junit5, parameterized-tests

Inorder to get multiple values for test case from JSON file, added the annotation @jsonfilesource  and passed JSONObject as parameter to the method in Mockito framework. But I am getting below exception

Error-
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException .Failed to resolve the parameter javax.json.JsonObject. caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodErroor org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.parametercontext

Without Mockito annotation @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class), it is working but other mockito related things are not working.
Please someone guide me how to configure @ParameterizedTest with JSON in MockitoFramework (JUNIT 5)
My sample code is given below,

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SampleTest{
@InjectMock
UserService a;
@Mock
UserDao b;

@ParameterizedTest
@JsonFileSource(resource="filepath")
public void sampleTestMethod(JsonObject obj){
}
}
```

Comment: Where is this @JsonFileSource annotation coming from? Could you provide the lib?